# UITableView reload data issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have had couple of encounters of this and what I am trying to do is basically calling `tableView reloadData` however not all the values in the cell is getting updated.The top 5 rows is always not updated... I'd have to scroll to the bottom and then up again to get it updated. Why is this happening?

Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16]];
    }


    //add a button to set to accessory view
    UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //I missed setting the frame yesterday!
    //[button setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 20, 20, 20)];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addsource.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    cell.accessoryView = button;

    if ([[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[Source class]]){
        Source * source = [self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if (![source.type isEqualToString:@"featured"]){
            [cell.textLabel setText:source.domain];
            NSURL* URL = [NSURL URLWithString:source.imageUrl];
            [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:URL
                           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"]];
        }
    }

    return cell;    
}
```

and this is called everytime I refresh the whole data set:

```
 [self.content removeAllObjects];
        [self.content addObjectsFromArray:objects];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: have you tried debugging? what does  `if (![source.type isEqualToString:@"featured"]){` return? obviously your cell won't get updated in the case where your source type is "featured". double check all values in your content array.

Comment: yes that is actually the issue

Comment: I will write it is an answer, so you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try debugging the following line:
`if (![source.type isEqualToString:@"featured"]){`

obviously your cell won't get updated in the case where your source type is "featured". double check all values in your content array

Answer (score 0):

I've not dug into your code, but this sounds like a symptom you might see when cells are being reused without being fully reset from their previous appearance.

When a cell gets dequeued, it doesn't get reset, it just gets removed from the table view. So unless you do reset it when it next happens to be allocated, it carry previous config and settings.

So, when you configure a cell, make sure you restore all aspects of the cell in all cases, not just those settings for a particular variant of the cell you happen to be returning this time.

Hope that helps.